# java regex or other way for finding string between string and other parts of that string

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a String like this

```
String s = "AZERTY<em>ZA</em> QWERTY OK <em>NE</em>NO ;
```

I want extract strings between  *and*  and construct a StringBuilder with all parts of the string in right order. I do this because i need to identify and localize the strings extracted but i need to keep the entire string too.
The purpose for all this work is to add later the entire String in a excel sheet cell and add font for the string between

```
XSSFRichTextString xssfrt = new XSSFRichTextString(); // acts like a StringBuilder
    xssfrt .append("AZERTY");
    xssfrt .append("ZA" , font); //extract 1
    xssfrt .append(" QWERTY OK "); // keep spaces
    xssfrt .append("NE" , font); //extract 2
    xssfrt .append("NO");
```

There is my regex which can extract the desired strings but i don't know how to construct the StringBuilder with all parts in right order :/

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\<em>(.*?)\\</em>");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(value);
            while(m.find())
            {
                m.group(1); //extracts
            }
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Matcher's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) appendReplacement(StringBuffer sb, String replacement) and appendTail(StringBuffer sb) function to keep it in order. And have a list which will store the extracted Strings. Something like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    String s = "AZERTY<em>ZA</em> QWERTY OK <em>NE</em>NO";
    String matchedString = null;
    List<String> extractedString = new ArrayList<String>();
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\<em>(.*?)\\</em>");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    while (m.find()) {

        matchedString = m.group(1);
        extractedString.add(matchedString);
        m.appendReplacement(sb, matchedString);
        sb.append(" ");

    }
    m.appendTail(sb);

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
    System.out.println(extractedString.toString());
}
Output :
String buffer = AZERTYZA  QWERTY OK NE NO
List of extracted String = [ZA, NE]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i need to construct a string builder not a simple string because i need to identify the strings extracted from other parts

Comment: @ulquiorra I have updated my answer please check whether it solves your problem. Only thing remains is there is no space between first word and first extracted string which I think you can handle. I have not used those functions extensively but I thought that is what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks . Works like a charm :)

Answer (score 2):

An easy fix is too add another group to match a string before `<em>`:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*?)<em>(.*?)</em>");
```

With it, `m.group(1)` refers to the string outside `em`, and `m.group(2)` is the one inside.

Of course, this won't include the last string outside `em` (`NO` in your example). So, you might want to memorize the last index where the matching ends with e.g. `int end = m.end()`, and retrieve it `s.substring(end)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] pieces = s.split("<.*?>")
```

This will split the string on anything surrounded by `<>`.
If your tag is always `em`, then you can use:

```
String[] pieces = s.split("</?em>")
```

Comment: Thanks . And how i can identify with split the strings between <em></em> from other parts ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like as :

```
        String str = "AZERTY<em>ZA</em> QWERTY OK <em>NE</em>NO";
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String[] parts = str.split("(<\\/?em>)");

        System.out.println("parts : "+Arrays.toString(parts));

        for(String s:parts){
            System.out.println("Part going to append :"+s);
            stringBuilder.append(s);
        }
        System.out.println("StringBuilder : "+stringBuilder.toString());
    }
```

Out put will be:

```
> parts : [AZERTY, ZA,  QWERTY OK , NE, NO] Part going to append :AZERTY
> Part going to append :ZA Part going to append : QWERTY OK  Part going
> to append :NE Part going to append :NO StringBuilder : AZERTYZA QWERTY
> OK NENO
```

UPDATES :--

Check the updated code:

```
String str = "AZERTY<em>ZA</em> QWERTY OK <em>NE</em>NO";

        //replace word in string which is preceded by <\em> to word:font eg. ZA:font
        str = str.replaceAll("(\\w+)(?=\\<\\/em\\>)", "$1:font");
   // After replace :AZERTY<em>ZA:font</em> QWERTY OK <em>NE:font</em>NO

        String[] parts = str.split("(<\\/?em>)");
 // After split : [AZERTY, ZA:font,  QWERTY OK , NE:font, NO]   

        XSSFRichTextString xssfrt = new XSSFRichTextString();

        for(String s:parts){
            //set font according to replace string
            if(s.contains(":")){
                String[] subParts = s.split(":");
                xssfrt.append(subParts[0], /**check the subParts[0] and set the font***/ );
            }else{
                xssfrt.append(s);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you but i need to identify "ZA" and "NE" in the StringBuilder . See my updated question thanks :)